# Compare Duplicate Data From a List with Inputed Data

Tags: java

I want to check duplicate IDs from a list with the data I inputted, then increment the qty variable in the list. If it's new data, it will add a new list.

This is my code

```
public void addBarang(Barang barang){
    int id_barang = barang.getId();
    if(this.list.isEmpty())
    {
         list.add(barang);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(list.get(i).getId() != id_barang)
            {
                list.add(barang);
                System.out.println("Added");
                break;
            }
            if(list.get(i).getId() == id_barang)
            {
                int new_qty = list.get(i).getQty()+barang.getQty();
                list.get(i).setQty(new_qty);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Even if I input new data it always increments the qty of old data and the new data is not added (basically always end in the "else" section).

Code for inputing data

```
Gudang gudang1 = new Gudang(1,1);
System.out.println("ID: ");
int id = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Jumlah: ");
int qty = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Nama: ");
String name = input.next();
Barang barang = new Barang(id,name,qty);
gudang1.addBarang(barang);
```

Barang Class

```
public class Barang {
public static int id;
private String name;
private int qty;

public Barang(int id, String name, int qty) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.qty = qty;
}

public Barang(){
};

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public int getQty() {
    return qty;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setQty(int qty) {
    this.qty = qty;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Barang{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", qty=" + qty + '}';
}
```

Gudang Class

```
public class Gudang {
public static int id;
private int location;
public List<Barang> list = new ArrayList<Barang>();

public Gudang(int id, int location) {
    Gudang.id = id;
    this.location = location;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public int getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public List<Barang> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setLocation(int location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public void setList(List<Barang> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

public void addBarang(Barang barang){
    int id_barang = barang.getId();
    if(this.list.isEmpty())
    {
         list.add(barang);
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            if(list.get(i).getId() != id_barang)
            {
                list.add(barang);
                System.out.println("Added");
                break;
            }
            if(list.get(i).getId() == id_barang)
            {
                int new_qty = list.get(i).getQty()+barang.getQty();
                list.get(i).setQty(new_qty);
            }
        } 
    }
   System.out.println("Size List = "+list.size());
}

public void duplicate(List<Barang> list2)
{
    this.list.addAll(list2);

}
public void clearBarang(){
    this.list.clear();
}

public void display(){
    for(Barang barang: this.list){
        System.out.println(barang);
    }
}
```

IE : If I have id=1 and qty=1, then input a new data with id=2 and qty=2, the final result will end up with id=2 and qty=3. No new data int he list were added.

Comment: Show us some more code i.e. complete function what are it's input parameters. Moreover, give some expected vs actual output ...

Comment: What is the exact type of `id` ? At first glance, the problem could be that you use the object `Long` and not the primitive `long`. So the `!=` won't work as expected.

Comment: Show “Gudang and Barang” classes ...

Answer (score 0):

try using .equals to compare if the data exist in your list

Answer (score 0):

Please check if ids are duplicate between your old and new data.

If you ids are unique then you can take advantage of Map and put id as key and barang object as value. Whenever you successfully lookup map increment quantity field of object.

Answer (score 0):

At first guess i would change:

```
if(list.get(i).getId() != id_barang)
```

to:

```
if(list.get(i).getId() != barang.getId())
```

maybe id_barang is not the same as the id stored in the barang object.